# How to add a nested JSONB field with sequelize/postgres

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

In `User` model, there is a `JSONB` field `viewer_data` which is currently `null` for instance `user`. A new field `jwt_secret` with value 1 needs to be added under `viewer_data`. It shall look like the following after adding `jwt_secret` under `viewer_data`:

```
  user : {viewer_data : {"jwt_token":1}}
```

Tried the `set` and `insert` and both of them are not working:

```
   user = await User.findByPk(id);
   console.log(user.viewer_data); //<<==output is null 
   //
   user.set("viewer_data.jwt_secret", 1); //<<==throw an error of can't convert null to object as viewer_data is null
   user.insert("view_data.jwt_secret", 1); //<<==error as insert is not a function
```

The postgres version is 11 and sequelize is 6.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the JSONB field `viewer_data` is null. a update shall be done like this:

```
  user.set("viewer_data", {"prev_jwt_secret": xxx, "jwt_secret": xxx}};
```